# Display events to angular angular full calendar

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, fullcalendar

calendar.html

```
<full-calendar 
  defaultView="dayGridMonth"
  [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
  [weekends]="true"
   [events]="[
        { title: 'event 1', date: '2019-06-07' },
    { title: 'event 2', date: '2019-06-12' }
  ]"
 ></full-calendar>
```

[and this how look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMu1Y.png)

everything is fine but ı want load event from json instead of “[events]” array and ı made service

schedule.ts

```
export class ScheduleProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello ScheduleProvider Provider');
  }

  getData():Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any[]>('url/events');

  }

}
```

this my json url/events

> {“data”:[{“id”:1,“name”:"subject 1"“start_time”:“2019-07-21
>   00:00:00”},{“id”:2,“name”:"subject 2"“start_time”:“2019-07-28
>   00:00:00”},{“id”:3,“name”:"subject 3"“start_time”:“2019-07-30
>   00:00:00”}]}

calendar.ts

```
jsonEvents:any=[];

 ngOnInit(){

    this.svc.getData().subscribe(data=>this.jsonEvents=data);

  }
```

ı dont know how to display jsonEvents in calendar instead of events array . So please help me.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed might help you

Comment: ı looked before  this  fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed   but  its so complex and ı am using and ı want to  pull event data  from url

Comment: why is it complex? It's designed to be simple - just enter the URL e.g `[events]="http://www.example.com/events.php"`, and it will work (if your server returns the data in the right format). What specifically about it is puzzling you? Did you try to use it? What went wrong?

Comment: The main issue I can see is that your JSON is not in a format fullCalendar can understand. 1) it must be just an array of events, no other data, and 2) you need to set the event object data using the correct property names which fullCalendar will recognise - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing . Nothing about this is too difficult I don't think, if you just take a moment to look at the documentation.

Comment: does my json url extension have to be in php? my url like this  localhost/api/events

Comment: ı tried before another url which is proper full calendar something like this   {"data":[{"id":1,"title":"firstevent","start":"2019-07-14 15:19:55"}]}  but it didnt work again

Comment: "does my json url extension have to be in php"...no, any server-side language will do. the browser making the AJAX request doesn't know, or care, what server-side language you used. All it cares about is that the JSON returned by the server is in the correct format. You could even just point it at a static text file containing JSON, if you wanted to

Comment: No, this `{"data":[{"id":1,"title":"firstevent","start":"2019-07-14 15:19:55"}]}` is not correct. Please refer back to my earlier comment where I said _" 1) it must be just an array of events, no other data"_. fullCalendar does not understand to look in your "data" property to get the events. Instead you must return the events and only the events, otherwise it won't work. i.e. just return `[{"id":1,"title":"firstevent","start":"2019-07-14 15:19:55"}]` and nothing else.

Comment: Is the wrong about name(data) of array of json ? For example if  name of array  be  "events"   instead of  "data"  then will it work properly

Comment: No, renaming it will not work. It must be **just the array**. No outer object, no property name, nothing. Just return the array **alone**, as per the example in my last comment. Sorry I thought I was very clear about this (and so is the fullCalendar documentation, IMO).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, in case you cannot change in the API to return the data in the format accepted by FullCalendar, could you try transforming the data, I've done it in the OnInit, following way:

1.call service to get the date
2.map the data to return only events from the response
3.simple loop to map data to the ones accepted by FullCalendar

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.eventService.getEvents(1000, 1).pipe(map(data=>data.events)).subscribe(
    data => {
      for(let d of data) {
        const date = new Date(d.dateStart)
        const simpleDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
        this.currentEvents.push({title: d.title, start: simpleDate, url: d.slug, end: d.dateEnd, allDay: true})
      }

      this.calendarOptions = {
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,listWeek,listYear'
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events: this.currentEvents,// alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
        eventColor: '#3F51B5',
        eventDisplay: 'auto',
        eventTextColor: '#FFFFFF',
        weekends: true,
        editable: false,
        selectable: false,
        selectMirror: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
        eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this)
      };
    }
  );
```